# Proving an elementary inequality of real vectors related to the p-Laplacian

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

How would you prove the following inequality?
$$
 \left|\left|a\right|^{p-2}a-\left|b\right|^{p-2}b\right|\leq C_p\left|a-b\right|^{p-1}
$$
where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $C_p>0$ is some constant depending only on $p$, $1<p<2$. The inequality is mentioned in http://www.math.ntnu.no/~lqvist/p-laplace.pdf on page 43 but proof is omitted. The same notes have a collection of inequalities at chapter 10, in particular the following inequality for euclidean inner product product is given
$$
(\left|a\right|^{p-2}a-\left|b\right|^{p-2}b)\cdot(a-b)\leq C_{p}\left|a-b\right|^{p}
$$
 but I'm not sure how to deduce the first inequality from this.

Comment: You got the powers wrong: should be $||a|^{p-2}a- \dots|$ on the l.h.s.

Comment: That's right. Fixed it.